# Estruturar Vue Components no Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, componentes

Olá sou iniciante com VueJs e estou tentando implementa-lo em um projeto Laravel 5.7 meu.

Atualmente possuo alguns *components* e estou para criar mais um tanto e vejo que fica meio bagunçado tudo "jogado" ali na pasta de componentes e então eu tentei criar umas pastas pra organizar de melhor forma, mas percebi que não consigo dar o

```
import MeuComponente from './minhaPasta/meuComponente.vue'
```

dentro dos meus componentes, pois ele não acha o componente, creio que eu não digitei nada errado mas ele não acha o arquivo.

Minha pergunta é: eu estou fazendo algo de errado ou realmente não tenho como estruturar os componentes do vuejs em pastas no laravel 5.7?

Se não tem como, como faço para deixar organizado meus componentes quando eu começar a ter uns 15+? E caso tenha como estruturar, peço que me ajudem.

Comment: Você está utilizando vue-cli??

Comment: Não, estou utilizando o que vem por "padrão" no laravel após a instalação via NPM INSTALL, eu apenas rodo o NPM RUN WATCH (obs: eu consigo acessar normalmente meus components que esta na pasta "components" mas não se estiverem por exemplo na "components/minhaPasta")

Comment: Sua pasta está dentro de `resources/js` ???

Comment: Sim, `resource/js/components/minhaPasta`

Comment: Os dois componentes estão no mesmo nível? Ou seja, ambos estão dentro de minhaPasta? Se sim, tentou acessar com `./meuComponente.vue`?

Comment: @guastallaigor não, o que estou tentando chamar esta no diretório MinhaPasta e o de qual estou chamando esta no components, mas quando coloco o seguinte código, não funciona: `import MeuComponent from ./minhaPasta/meuComponent.vue`